# Template in Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile the GfxTL library for Android, which is in C++. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and NDK r16b with Clang 5.0.300080 compiler. However, I'm having the following error with some functions:

`error: use of undeclared identifier 'ExistChild'`

It uses the `ExistChild` function in the `KdTree` class, which the inherits the class `BaseTree`, which implements this function.

```
class KdTree
: public StrategiesT::template StrategyBase
    <
        MetricT
        <
            VectorKernelT
            <
                BaseTree
                <
                    KdTreeCell< typename StrategiesT::CellData >
                >
            >
        >
    >
{
    ...
};
```

Since this code compiles in Visual Studio, I suspect that the problem may be that the Android C++ compiler does not support this kind of template specialization. I searched around and I couldn't find any information that confirms or denies this.

Does anybody encounter this problem before?

Comment: Can you add which compiler (and version) you are using from the NDK.

Comment: @RichardCritten, I'm using Clang (version 5.0.300080). Forgot to mention in the original question.